# What does this error mean? - 'Array operation attempted on variable not DIM'd.'

Tags: roku, brightscript

While parsing some JSON I came across this error. `body` is an associative array. The debugger stopped at this line.

`itemTitle = body["title"]`

The whole error message is

`Array operation attempted on variable not DIM'd. (runtime error &he7) in $LIVECOMPILE(4)`

Answer (score 2):

This happens when you try to use an array accessor on a string. For example,

```
str1 = "hello"
title = str1["title"] ' error - Array operation attempted on variable not DIM'd.
```